# PHP - how to avoid use for extended classes when using type hinted constructors?

Tags: php

I want to avoid having to type the use statements for extended classes.  It seems like it should be redundant, since the parent class knows the type for the type hinting?

For example I have a parent class

```
/* parent.php */
<?php
namespace App\ParentClass;

use App\User;
use App\Request;

class ParentClass {
    public function __construct(
        User $user,
        Request $request
    )
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

and a child class

```
/* parent.php */
<?php
namespace App\ChildClass;

use App\ParentClass\ParentClass;

// HOW CAN I ELIMINATE HAVING TO TYPE THE use STATEMENTS HERE?
use App\User;
use App\Request;

class ChildClass extends ParentClass 
{
    public function __construct(
        User $user,
        Request $request
    )
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: `use` is per file and not inheritable as far as I know.

Comment: Like replacing `use App\User;` in file header with `App\User $user` in constructor parameters?

Comment: `HOW CAN I ELIMINATE...` use the full name in the constructor instead `__construct(\App\User $User, \App\Request $Request)`.  And `TYPE THE...` does your tool (like phpstrom) not type it for you?

Comment: If you could eliminate the `use`-statements in the child classes (without using the full namespace in the constructor), your code would fail if there was another `User`-class in the same namespace as the child class. PHP wouldn't know which to use (pardon the pun)...

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson If `eliminating` then global, not only in the child class, in the base class too. Then that can become a Rule in your personal coding guide ;) Always full-qualified names in the constructor :) But , never mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot omit such use clause,

because you are using `User` and `Request` classes below in constructor, so php need to know about this classes.

Comment: But shouldn't the type hinting be able to use the parent class by default?  AFAIK I can't pass a different type so unless I override with a type extended from User or Request, it seems like the type hinted types shouldn't have to be re-used?

Comment: @Josh Petitt What you are missing here is: `use` helps to get the full name of the class and that must be defined correct in each file.

Comment: No, type hinting helpless in this case.

Comment: I accepted the first answer, since it was correct.  Thanks everyone for the help :-)

Comment: @JoshPetitt Default namespace is the one set with the `namespace` keyword and, thankfully, there aren't exceptions to care about like the one you suggest.

Comment: Thank you! I, also agree with @Álvaro González, and i upvoted him answer  especially for point 3.

Answer (score 2):

Extended classes have no way to "know" the namespace of arbitrary parameters because:

1. You can have classes with the same name in different namespaces (that's the idea of namespaces in the first place)
2. Code in a namespace can use objects from other namespaces
3. Child classes constructors can have entirely different parameters than parent constructors.